# Midpoint of each Sefer

Tags: words, pentateuch-chumash, aleph-bet-letters, mathematics

I am looking for sources that tell what word, letter and verse is at the midpoint of each Sefer, meaning 5 midpoints if considering the Torah containing 5 books or if you want, 7 as the Talmud states since Sefer Bamidbar can be divided into 3 with before Vayehi Binsoah Aaron, after it and what’s in between the inverveted nuns.

Comment: The Midpoint of the Middle Sefer Vayikra is What and What it is framed in נ Nun Upside Down making Seven Books of Moshe Rabbeinu Na NaCh

Comment: This is at the verse Wayhi Binsoa Num 10:35 look at it well it's the fourth book but the last three books are one in a way It's one volume in the Holy Zohar. Na NaCh

Comment: Midpoint of which measure- words, letters, pesukim, etc?

Comment: What is Chatzi chel sefer Bereshi (and Shemot, Vayikra, Devraim) for the words, the verses an the letters is the question?

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1883118/jewish/What-Is-the-Midpoint-of-the-Torah.htm

Comment: All of these are indicated by the Luach HaSimanim at the end of each of the five books of the Chumash. It would be relevant to your question to note if you are counting by sentences, words or letters for your halfway mark to each sefer.